# Map appsettings.json to Dictionary<string, Value>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have the following configuration

```
"Options": {
  "Host": "123",
  "UserName": "test",
  "Password": "test",
  "Files": [
    {
      "Key": "asd",
      "Value": {
        "HostLocation": "asd",
        "RemoteLocation": "asd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm trying to bind it to the following object

```
public class Options
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, FileOptions> Files { get; set; }

    public class FileOptions
    {
        public string HostLocation { get; set; }
        public string RemoteLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is when I'm trying to bind the the Files to the dictionary. They don't get bound. I get a key generated with the value of 1, and the value FileOptions are generated all with default string value.

This is my configuration mapping.

```
_serviceCollection.Configure<SftpOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("Options"));
```

What is wrong and how can I map the setting into the Options class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They don't get bound. I get a key generated with the value of 1, and the value FileOptions are generated all with default string value.

Which is correct since `Files` is an array in the shown JSON

```
  "Files": [
    {
      "Key": "asd",
      "Value": {
        "HostLocation": "asd",
        "RemoteLocation": "asd"
      }
    }
  ]
```

The JSON would need to look like the following to satisfy the desired object graph

```
"Options": {
  "Host": "123",
  "UserName": "test",
  "Password": "test",
  "Files": {
      "asd": {
        "HostLocation": "asd",
        "RemoteLocation": "asd"
      },
      "someOtherKey" : {
        "HostLocation": "something",
        "RemoteLocation": "something"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting for anyone who encounters this answer, that all of the members of your Options class must be Properties.  You might think you can use a public field and decorate it with the [JsonInclude] attribute, but that doesn't work in this circumstance!